# How to find an alert dialog through selenium using Appium?

Tags: java, selenium, android-testing, appium

A dialog is implemented in such way in the app:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Something");
builder.setTitle("Something");
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

How could I find this element in Appium testing script?

`driver.switchTo().alert();` throws `NotImplementError`

`driver.findElement(By.tagName("AlertDialog"))` is not working

And I found this issue [Alert methods NYI](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/307) on Github. Is there any workaround about this?

By the way, I'm not going to click on "OK" or "Cancel" on that dialog, I'm about to wait until that dialog disappears automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Please use the below code for your need:

To wait for the alert to appear:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

To wait for the alert to disappear:

```
wait.until(!ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works when I do this to accept alert dialog with OK button

```
driver.findElement(By.name("OK")).click()
```

But after the click action is completed my program stops detecting elements

Comment: They don't want to dismiss the alert, they need to wait until it dismisses automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the alert to disappear:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()));
```